# batch script to create random users in active directory/local system

Tags: batch-file, random, scripting

I'm trying to create a batch script that will insert random users into a system (with a random password):

So far I have:

```
@TITLE New User Creation
@ECHO Creating a new user . . .

for /l %%x in (1, 1, 100) do net user %RANDOM% /add

@PAUSE
```

---

Secondly I'm trying to see if I can use dsadd user %RANDOM% -pwd %RANDOM% to add them into a Active Directory server. However, how can I make the batch script loop 100 times and create 100 users and having the %RANDOM% variable meet the complexity of the server?

Any assistance with this would be helpful!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This creates random usernames and passwords, each comprising 8 digits and does it 100 times.

It is not guaranteed to give 100 unique names, but it may well do so.

It just displays the password, doesn't implement it.

```
@echo off
TITLE New User Creation
ECHO Creating users . . .
set c=0
:loop
set num=%random%%random%%random%%random%
if %num% LSS 1000000000 goto :loop
set pw=%num:~0,8%
set num=%num:~-8%
set /a c+=1
echo user: %num% password: %pw%
net user %num% /add
if %c% LSS 100 goto :loop
Pause
```

Comment: This works but I assume there is no way for the password to be implemented? I mean, even if this script were to be used in Powershell for Active Directory? The main goal is to be able to add them on a AD server so I can use the accounts as dummy accounts.

Comment: I have no experience with AD.  Is there a command line that will add users, and allow passwords?  You can use the batch file to create a text file with the 100 names:passwords and that can be used in a Powershell script.  You'll need to open a new question regarding that.

Comment: `Net user %num% %pw% /add` should create the users with password - do they then get migrated to AD??

Comment: As far as I am aware, you can add using Powershell via the "dsadd user" command but I am unable to make a script that actually implements a user. The net user is for a local system. Though, I doubt it populates the Active Directory user list.